# Javascript - find out first element appears in sorted array as well as in another unsorted collection

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, filter

I have an array of unsorted number and another array of sorted number, like

```
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 9, 11];
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, ...., 100]
```

How could I find out the `first element` appears in my `sortedArray` which should also be an element existed in my `unSortedArray`? In above example, should return 9 because 9 existed in unSortedArray as well as it positioned prior to other element in sortedArray

Note, I used 1, 2, 3, 4 in my above example, but my real world example was not number but is **GUID**, let's say we **cannot apply sort method on `unSortedArray`** then pick the first element.

I have thought about union both arrays, but how to union both while not break the sorting in sortedArray?

Here is some example

1) output should be 1, because even element 1, 2, 9 and 10 exists in both array, 1 has prior order than 2, 9, 10 in sortedArray

```
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 9, 10, 2, 1]; 
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

2) output should be 9, because even element 9 and 10 exists in both array, 9 has prior order than 10 in sortedArray

```
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 10, 9]; 
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

3) output should be '' because no element in unSortedArray appears in sorted Array

```
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 11]; 
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do it with a for loop:

```js
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 9, 11];
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let firstVal;
for (i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
  if (unSortedArray.includes(sortedArray[i])) {
    firstVal = sortedArray[i];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(firstVal);
```

Comment: You could make it a one-liner using reduce(): `console.log(sortedArray.reduce((acc,val) => unSortedArray.includes(val) ? val : acc));`

Comment: Short for "accumulator". It's the variable which contains the return value of the function inside the `reduce()`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Hi @Ed Lucas, there seems a bug with `sortedArray.reduce((acc,val) => unSortedArray.includes(val) ? val : acc)`, if unSortedArray does not contain any element in sorted Array, then it will return the first element in sortedArray somehow, is there any way to return null or undefined?

Comment: You can set a default value for the accumulator by using the second parameter of `reduce()`: `sortedArray.reduce((acc,val) => unSortedArray.includes(val) ? val : acc, null)`

Comment: somehow this won't work if in below example
```
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 9, 11, 1, 2];
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const first = sortedArray.reduce((acc,val) => unSortedArray.includes(val) ? val : acc, '');
console.log(first);
```
It always output 9 instead of 1...

Comment: I think the issue is due to reduce always treat array element from left to right?

Comment: The reduce is not really the best solution, since it's checking every item in sortedArray, but here's a fix to stop setting the accumulator after it finds the first match: `sortedArray.reduce((acc,val) => !acc && unSortedArray.includes(val) ? val : acc, '');`

Comment: That works it out! I may need to spend time to understand the expression here..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the `unSortedArray` and use [`set.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) in your predicate for [`sortedArray.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const unSortedArray = [54, 23, 55, 76, 9, 11];
const sortedArray= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const setHasValue = set => value => set.has(value);
const firstElement = sortedArray.find(setHasValue(new Set(unSortedArray)));

console.log(firstElement);
```

Comment: My two arrays value are already distinct for each, is that because we want to use Set.has that we need to declare a Set here?

Comment: @KevDing it isn't about uniqueness, it's about the time complexity of `set.has()` O(1) vs. `array.includes()` O(n)

Comment: Thanks for considering that!

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to construct a look up table for unsorted array items. Such as

```
{ 54: true
, 23: true
, 55: true
.
.
  11: true
}
```

This would be an O(k) task where `k` is the number of elements of the unsorted array. Then `find` the first item in the sorted array that returns `true`. This should be an O(n) task where `n` is the number of elements of the sorted array. Yielding a linear time solution.

This should do it.

```js
function getFirst(usa,sa){
  var h = usa.reduce((r,n) => (r[n] = true, r), {});
  return sa.find(n => h[n]);
}

var r = getFirst([54,23,55,76,9,11], Array.from({length:100}, (_,i) => i+1));
console.log(r);
```